# For a map of objects, can I emplace objects, or just pairs?

Tags: c++, c++11, hashmap, multimap, emplace

I'm using C++ 11 and gcc-4.7.0. I'm looking for an STL solution.

I'd like to have an unsorted multimap that contains objects of myClass with short strings as keys. Emplace looks like a good way to put the objects into the map as I construct them, but I'm not sure if it can do that, or if it will only construct the key/object pair.
This should be valid:

```
table.emplace(myKey, myClass(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

But would it be more efficient to do the following, and is it even valid code?

```
table.emplace(myKey, arg1, arg2, arg3);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.7.2/libstdc++/manual/manual/status.html#status.iso.2011), `gcc-4.7` does not fully support `emplace()`.

`gcc-4.8` would have fully support of `emplace()`, but would require a little differnt syntax:

```
table.emplace(std::piecewise_construct, std::forward_as_tuple(myKey), std::forward_as_tuple(arg1, arg2, arg3));
```

instead of

```
table.emplace(myKey, arg1, arg2, arg3); // Does not work.
```

For `forward` to take effect for rvalue, one could use `std::move()` to wrap around the arguments.

So it will directly contruct both key and value in place in the container.

`std::piecewise_construct` is an [argument](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/piecewise_construct) for special usage of `std::pair` constructor. It will ask the constructor to forward the arguments individually to underlying constructor.

This is actually an issue of `emplace()` for associative containers. The original intention is to use the first argument for key, and the following arguments for value, like what is described in the question. See [this](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-closed.html#2006) for further details on this issue.

Thanks to Zeta, for pointing out `forward` issue.

Comment: If your going for efficiency, you might want to use `forward_as_tuple` instead of `make_tuple`, however, keep the usual `forward` related things in mind.